# check constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

hi i want add constraint in sql server i try this but not work 
i needd check if a word 2 char and 3 numbers after example aa192:

```
create table test(
    idtest int primary key ,
    neEdition varchar(50)
);

alter table test add constraint ch_like check(neEdition like'[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]');
```

Comment: How does this not work?

Comment: Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicts with the CHECK "ch_like" constraint. The conflict occurred in the database "EFF2017", table "dbo.test", column 'neEdition'.

Comment: This means you have data in the table that violates your constraint. You can find it with `SELECT * FROM dbo.test WHERE neEdition not like'[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works in [rextester](http://rextester.com/HSYGI25264).

Given what you are doing, I would recommend that the edition be declared to have 5 characters:

```
neEdition varchar(5)
```

or:

```
neEdition char(5)
```

That is more consistent with the check constraint.

Comment: Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 The ALTER TABLE statement conflicts with the CHECK "ch_like" constraint. The conflict occurred in the database "EFF2017", table "dbo.test", column 'neEdition'. –